# Error in saving a text file in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

This is to save the arrays in the disk.

```
 import numpy as np, itertools

x1 = np.linspace(0.1, 3.5, 3)
x2 = np.arange(5, 24, 3)
x3 = np.arange(50.9, 91.5, 3)

def calculate(x1,x2,x3):
    res = x1**5+x2*x1+x3
    return res

products = np.array(list(itertools.product(x1,x2,x3)))

results = np.array([calculate(a,b,c) for a,b,c in products])
print results

np.savetxt('test.out', (products,results))
```

The error is :

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (294,3) into shape (294)
```

How to solve it?
**The outfile will look like as follows:**

```
0.1   5.   50.9  51.40001
0.1   5.   53.9  54.40001
```

Comment: How do you want the output file to look like?

Comment: @plonser I have shown it in my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to glue the two arrays together in a compatible way. The easiest way is probably

```
arr_combined = np.column_stack((products,results))

np.savetxt('test.out',arr_combined)
```

`np.column_stack` adds one dimensional arrays as column vectors to a 2d array.

Comment: add format argument to get the output same as in output example, otherwise you will get  someting like this:  1.000000000000000056e-01 5.000000000000000000e+00 5.089999999999999858e+01 5.140001000000000175e+01  np.savetxt('test.out',arr_combined,fmt='%1.f %1.1f %1.1f %1.5f')